# Install android sdk in eclipse without downloading full os

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, installation, storage

I would like to install the SDK for several android platforms on my chromebook using Ubuntu with crouton when I get it. The problem is that the chromebook I might get only has 16gb minus the OS. Installing the android SDK to eclipse also seems to install the whole emulator as well and it takes up A LOT of storage. Last time I did it I install 3 SDKs and the total space was almost 10gb.

Is there a way to install just the bare essentials for android development?

I don't want to run an emulator since I have several devices at my disposal and the chromebook won't be able to handle it anyway. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a JDK installed, the bare minimum you need for Android development is the standalone SDK, the platform tools, and at least one version of the Android platform.  All of that takes up less than 1/2gb.

You can get the standalone SDK from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).  Scroll down to the bottom and it's under Other Download Options / SDK Tools only.  Once you have that downloaded and unzipped somewhere, go into the android-sdk-linux/tools directory and run the android command there.  It will popup the Android SDK manager.  Uncheck everything except for the following and click install:

Tools

- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools

Android 5.1.1. (API 22) // or different version

- SDK Platform
- Google APIs

Extras

- Android Support Library
- other packages if your app needs them

You can find more information about how to use the standalone SDK for setting up your project and whatnot [here](http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/09/command-line-android-development-basics/).